# TouchableOpacity is slow when dispatch is used

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

I am using react-redux with redux-toolkit

```
import { setLanguage } from "../../redux/main";


   <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          dispatch(setLanguage("English"));
        }}
   >
```

Above code is working fine and it is updating the state globally for me, but problem is TouchableOpacity or pressable or TouchableHighlight is delayed by 500 ms to 2 seconds.

I tried             **delayPressIn={0}** with no result.

if i remove   `dispatch(setLanguage("English"))` , Button click is  working fast.

I thought Language state renders multiple component , that is why it is slow .. So I created dummy state which is not used anywhere , still I get this performance issue.

Comment: Problem is probably the long render time, you can check this by using `Flipper` or `react-devtools`. When update redux state, redux is re-rendering every page that used the language state, and if you've used it in so much components it can take a really long time to complete render

Comment: Yea I thought of it , thats why i created dummy state which is not used anywhere else , still there is delay.

Comment: @Graciewilliams hii... how did you fix that issue? have you fixed it? i am facing same issue. I am using redux dispatch for add cart button, if i have a large items it causes delay when on press TouchableOpacity.

Comment: hi , i was not able to fix it .. when i run the build it was little fast